# Python crawler to download images and other data

Tags: python

The site that I'm trying to crawl contains thousands of users pages that I would like to grab and output on another site. For instance, example.com lists a user photo, a name and title. The code would look similar to this:

```
<a href="/tommy"><img src="userphoto"></a>
<h1 class="username">Tommy</h1>
<p class="headline">President</p>
```

To get to the pages I need to crawl, you would go to example.com?id=1 and all the way through id 100. Each page contains about 50 users. How can I crawl each of the 100 pages on example.com, grab the user photo, name and title and then output this content on another site? Please help!

Comment: Use Scrapy. Doing what you want will be pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it on your own using:

- `for` to get `id` from 1 to 100
- `requests` to get page
- `lxml` or `BeautifulSoup` to get elements on page
- `requests` (again) or `pyCurl` to download images

Or you can use framework `Scrapy`

In both situations you will have to learn it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to use code that somebody else has already written, give [scrapy](http://scrapy.org/) a try.  It's pretty full-featured.